# infinite-dimensional linear program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let $\Delta^{n-1}$ denote the $(n-1)$-dimensional probability simplex, i.e. the set of all probability distributions of some $n$-dimensional state.

I have to find the optimal function $a:\Delta^{n-1}\rightarrow [0,1]^n$ to minimize the following:

\begin{align*}
&\min_{a} \sum^n_{j=1}q_j\int\limits_{p \in \Delta^{n-1}}c_j(p)a_j(p)dp\\
&\text{s.t.}\;(a(p)-a(p'))\cdot p \geq 0\;\forall\;p,p' \in \Delta^{n-1}. 
\end{align*}

My conjecture is that the optimal solution must consist of finitely many *linear* partitions of the space $\Delta^{n-1}$ such that $a(\cdot)$ is constant over each of them.

My approach so far: If the constraint from $p$ to $p'$ binds, i.e. if $p\cdot (a(p')-a(p))=0$, the one from $p'$ to $p''$ binds as well, for any $p''$ which is a convex combination of $p$ and $p'$, i.e. $p'\cdot(a(p'')-a(p'))=0.$ It follows from simple algebra with the constraints.

After that I'm not able to proceed further. Any help is most appreciated.